# Отправка емейла PHP с Bcc или Cc

Tags: php, email

Есть форма и PHP скрипт обработки
$form['form-4'] = сама форма
вопрос - как вытянуть значение поля  e-mail из формы и послать туда BCC или CC копию?
я добавил

```
$toemailcccopy = isset([$form['fields']['e-mail']]['value']);
$headers .= "Cc:".$toemailcccopy."\r\n";
```

но не работает
мои познания в PHP не позволяют мне сделать проверку что не так(

```
<?php

$act = isset($_REQUEST['act']) ? $_REQUEST['act'] : die('error');
$params = isset($_REQUEST['json']) ? json_decode($_REQUEST['json'], true) : array();
$jsonBox = array();
$error = array();
$info = array();
$exemple = array();
$form = array();
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
     $form['form-4'] = array(
            'fields' => array(
                'name' => array(
                    'title' => 'Имя',
                    'validate' => array(
                        'preg' => '%[A-Z-a-zА-Яа-я\s]%',
                        'minlength' => '3',
                        'maxlength' => '35',
                    ),
                    'messages' => array(
                        'preg' => 'Поле [ %1$s ] возможно содержит ошибку',
                        'minlength' => 'Минимальная длинна поля [ %1$s ] меньше допустимой - %2$s',
                        'maxlength' => 'Максимальная длинна поля [ %1$s ] превышает допустимую - %2$s',
                    )
                ),
                'tell' => array(
                    'title' => 'Телефон',
                    'validate' => array(
                        'preg' => "/^((8|\+)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{5,10}$/",
                        'minlength' => '5',
                    ),
                    'messages' => array(
                        'preg' => 'Поле [ %1$s ] возможно содержит ошибку',
                        'minlength' => 'Минимальная длинна поля [ %1$s ] меньше допустимой - %2$s',
                    )
                ),
                'e-mail' => array(
                    'title' => 'E-mail',
                    'validate' => array(
                        'preg' => '%@%is',
                        'minlength' => '5',
                    ),
                    'messages' => array(
                        'preg' => 'Поле [ %1$s ] возможно содержит ошибку',
                        'minlength' => 'Минимальная длинна поля [ %1$s ] меньше допустимой - %2$s',
                    )
                ),
                'text' => array(
                    'title' => 'Сообщение',
                    'validate' => array(
                        'minlength' => '1',
                    ),
                    'messages' => array(
                        'minlength' => '[ %1$s ] необходимо заполнить',
                    )
                ),
                'checkbox' => array(
                    'title' => 'Checkbox',
                    'validate' => array(
                        'minlength' => '1',
                    ),
                    'messages' => array(
                        'minlength' => '[ %1$s ] необходимо установить',
                    )
                ),
                'radio' => array(
                    'title' => 'Radio',
                    'validate' => array(
                        'minlength' => '1',
                    ),
                    'messages' => array(
                        'minlength' => '[ %1$s ] необходимо выбрать',
                    )
                ),
                'select' => array(
                    'title' => 'Select',
                    'validate' => array(
                        'minlength' => '1',
                    ),
                    'messages' => array(
                        'minlength' => '[ %1$s ] необходимо выбрать',
                    )
                ),
            ),
            'cfg' => array(
                'charset' => 'utf-8',
                'subject' => 'Тема письма',
                'title' => 'Заголовок в теле письма',
                'ajax' => true,
                'validate' => true,
                'from_email' => 'noreply@email.com',
                'from_name' => 'noreply',
                'to_email' => 'noreply1@email.com, noreply2@email.com',
                'to_name' => 'noreply1, noreply2',
                'geoip' => true,
                'referer' => true,
                'type' => 'plain',
                'tpl' => false,
                'antispam' => 'email77',
                'antispamjs' => 'address77',
                'okay' => 'Сообщение отправлено - OK',
                'fuck' => 'Сообщение отправлено - ERROR',
                'spam' => 'Cпам робот',
                'notify' => 'color-modal',
                'usepresuf' => false
            )
        );




        if($act == 'cfg') {
           $jsonBox['configs'] = ExportConfigs($form);
            die(json_encode($jsonBox));
        }

        function ExportConfigs($form) {
            $need = array('antispam','antispamjs','notify');
            $conf = array();
             foreach($form as $name => $data) {
                 foreach($data['cfg'] as $k => $cfg) {
                   if(in_array($k, $need)) {
                       $conf[$name]['cfg'][$k] = $cfg;
                   }
                 }
             }

            return $conf;
        }


        if(isset($form[$act])) {

           $form = $form[$act];
           $getdata = array();
           $sb = array(); // subject и body


              foreach($form['fields'] as $name => $field) {

                    $title = (isset($field['title'])) ? $field['title'] : $name;
                    $getdata[$name]['title'] = $title;
                    $rawdata = isset($_POST[$name]) ? trim($_POST[$name]) : '';

                      if(isset($field['validate'])) {              

                          $def = 'Поле с именем [ '.$name.' ] содержит ошибку.';
                          // -0-
                          if(isset($field['validate']['required']) &&
                              empty($rawdata)) {
                              $error[$name] = isset($field['messages']['required']) ? sprintf($field['messages']['required'], $title) :
                                             (isset($messages['validator']['required']) ? sprintf($messages['validator']['required'], $title) : $def);
                          }
                          // -1-
                          if(isset($field['validate']['minlength']) &&
                              mb_strlen($rawdata) < $field['validate']['minlength']) {
                              $error[$name] = isset($field['messages']['minlength']) ? sprintf($field['messages']['minlength'], $title, $field['validate']['minlength']) : $def;
                          }
                          // -2-
                          if(isset($field['validate']['maxlength']) &&
                            mb_strlen($rawdata) > $field['validate']['maxlength']) {
                                $error[$name] = isset($field['messages']['maxlength']) ? sprintf($field['messages']['maxlength'], $title, $field['validate']['maxlength']) : $def;
                          }
                          // -3-
                          if(isset($field['validate']['preg']) && mb_strlen($rawdata) > 0 &&
                              !preg_match($field['validate']['preg'], $rawdata)) {
                              $error[$name] = isset($field['messages']['preg']) ? sprintf($field['messages']['preg'], $title, $field['validate']['preg']) : $def;
                          }
                          // -4-
                          if(isset($field['validate']['substr']) &&
                              mb_strlen($rawdata) > $field['validate']['substr']) {
                              $rawdata = mb_substr($rawdata, 0, $field['validate']['substr']);
                          }

                       $outdata = htmlspecialchars($rawdata);

                       $getdata[$name]['value'] = $outdata;

                      }
                       else {
                         $getdata[$name]['value'] = htmlspecialchars($rawdata);
                      }

                       if(empty($getdata[$name]['value'])) {
                             unset($getdata[$name]);
                          }


              } //foreach end


            if(isset($form['cfg']['antispam']) && isset($_POST[$form['cfg']['antispam']])) {
                if(!empty($_POST[$form['cfg']['antispam']])) {
                 $error[] = $form['cfg']['spam'];
                }
            }
             if(isset($form['cfg']['antispamjs']) && isset($_POST[$form['cfg']['antispamjs']])) {
                 if(!empty($_POST[$form['cfg']['antispamjs']])) {
                     $error[] = $form['cfg']['spam'];
                 }
             }


            if(count($error) == 0) {

              if(function_exists("mb_internal_encoding")) mb_internal_encoding($form['cfg']['charset']);
              $get_fromName = (isset($form['fields'][$form['cfg']['from_name']]) && isset($getdata[$form['cfg']['from_name']]['value']) && mb_strlen($getdata[$form['cfg']['from_name']]['value']) > 2) ? $getdata[$form['cfg']['from_name']]['value'] : ((mb_strlen($form['cfg']['from_name']) > 2 && !isset($_POST[$form['cfg']['from_name']])) ? $form['cfg']['from_name'] : 'Anonymous');
              $get_fromEmail = (isset($form['fields'][$form['cfg']['from_email']]) && isset($getdata[$form['cfg']['from_email']]['value']) && mb_strpos('@', $getdata[$form['cfg']['from_email']]['value']) === false) ? $getdata[$form['cfg']['from_email']]['value'] : ((mb_strpos('@', $form['cfg']['from_email']) !== false) ? $form['cfg']['from_email'] : 'no-reply@'.$host);

              $fromName = (function_exists("mb_encode_mimeheader")) ? mb_encode_mimeheader($get_fromName, $form['cfg']['charset'], "Q") : $get_fromName;
              $sb['subject'] = (function_exists("mb_encode_mimeheader")) ? mb_encode_mimeheader($form['cfg']['subject'], $form['cfg']['charset'], "Q") : $form['cfg']['subject'];

              $toName = trim($form['cfg']['to_name'], " ,");
              $toEmail = trim($form['cfg']['to_email'], " ,");
              $toemailcccopy = isset([$form['fields']['e-mail']]['value']);


              if(strpos($toName, ",") !== false) { 
                 $exp_toName = explode(",", $toName);   
                 $c = count($exp_toName);
                  for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
                   $exp_toName[$i] = (function_exists("mb_encode_mimeheader")) ? mb_encode_mimeheader(trim($exp_toName[$i]), $form['cfg']['charset'], "Q") : trim($exp_toName[$i]);
                  } 
               } 
                else {
                  $toName = (function_exists("mb_encode_mimeheader")) ? mb_encode_mimeheader($toName, $form['cfg']['charset'], "Q") : $toName;
               }

              if(strpos($toEmail, ",") !== false) { 
                 $exp_toEmail = explode(",", $toEmail);
              }         

              $To = '';

               if(isset($exp_toEmail)) {
                $c = count($exp_toEmail);
                  for($i=0; $i < $c; $i++) { 
                       $To .= ((isset($exp_toName) && isset($exp_toName[$i])) ? $exp_toName[$i] : $toName) . " <".trim($exp_toEmail[$i]).">";
                       if($i < ($c-1)) $To .= ", ";
                   }
               } 
                else {
                   $To = ((isset($exp_toName) && isset($exp_toName[0])) ? $exp_toName[0] : $toName)." <".$toEmail.">";
               }


              $headers = "Return-Path: <".$get_fromEmail.">\r\n";
              $headers .= "From: ".$fromName." <".$get_fromEmail.">\r\n";
              $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
              $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$fromName." <".$get_fromEmail.">\r\n";
              $headers .= "Cc:".$toemailcccopy."\r\n";
              //$headers .= "To: ".$To."\r\n";
              $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
              $headers .= "Content-Type: text/" . $form['cfg']['type'] . "; charset=\"" . $form['cfg']['charset'] . "\"\r\n";
              $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";

              $sb['body'] = "";
              // парсим шаблон
              if($form['cfg']['tpl']) {
               $out = tpl(array('name' => $act, 'getdata' => $getdata, 'cfg' => $form['cfg']));
               if(is_string($out)) {
                  $sb['body'] = $out;
               }
             }
              // или отдаем голый текст
                if(mb_strlen(trim($sb['body'])) < 10) {
                  if(isset($form['cfg']['title']))
                      $sb['body'] .= $form['cfg']['title']."\r\n\r\n";
                  foreach($getdata as $name => $data) {
                      $sb['body'] .= $data['title'].": ".$data['value']."\r\n";
                  }
                  if($form['cfg']['referer'])
                      $sb['body'] .= "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n".$ref;
              }
              // если есть что добавить
               if(isset($form['cfg']['adds']) &&
                  is_array($form['cfg']['adds'])) {
                  $sb = adds($sb);
               }

              //отправка письма
              $mail = mail($To, $sb['subject'], $sb['body'], $headers);

              if($mail) {
                  $jsonBox['ok'] = 1;
                  $info[] = $form['cfg']['okay'];

                 //setcookie("limit", "1", time() + $form['cfg']['limit']);

              }
               else {
                   $info[] = $form['cfg']['fuck'];
               }

            }

         } else {
            $error[] = 'Нет настроек формы с именем #'.$act;
         }

            if(count($error) > 0) {
                $jsonBox['errors'] = $error;
            }
            if(count($info) > 0) {
                $jsonBox['infos'] = $info;
            }

            die(json_encode($jsonBox)); //мертвые с косами

        /* добавляет любые доп данные из вне в нужное место
         * (например в заголовок письма необходимо дабавить Ник юзера или Номер заказа )
         *
         *  */

        function adds($vars) {
            global $form;
            $adds = $form['cfg']['adds'];
            foreach($adds as $key => $opts) {
                if(is_string($key)) {
                    $one = array();
                    $two = array();
                    foreach($opts as $i => $val) {
                        if(isset($_POST[$val])) {
                          $one[] = '%%'.$val.'%%';
                          $two[] = $_POST[$val];
                        }
                    }
                   $vars[$key] = str_replace($one, $two, $vars[$key]);
                }
            }
               return $vars;
        }
        /*
         * парсер шаблона
         */
         function tpl($vars) {
            $tpl = 'tpl/'.$vars['name'].'.tpl';
            if(file_exists($tpl)) {
             $template = file_get_contents($tpl);
                foreach($vars['getdata'] as $name => $data) {
                    $template = str_replace(array("%%".$name.".title%%", "%%".$name.".value%%"), array($data['title'], $data['value']), $template);
                }
                return $template;
            }
             else {
              return false;
            }
         }
```

частично решил
добавил данный код, но **он не шлет на указаный** в Input name="e-mail" емейл письмо, а **только на указанный в Else** mail@site.com

```
$form = array();
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

  if (isset($_GET["e-mail"])  && mb_strlen($_GET["e-mail"]) > 6) {
  $toemailcccopy = $_GET["e-mail"]; }
else {
    $toemailcccopy ="mail@site.com";
  } ;
$headers .= "Cc: ".$toemailcccopy."\r\n";
```

пинком отправьте в сторону где рыть(((

Comment: Уточнение вопроса пишите в вопросе (внизу вопроса ссылка `править`). Ответы пишите в ответах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

висел еще  обработчик JS
я считывал Get

```
<form action="" method="get" name="form-1">
```

а он менял на POST
отсюда и пустое поле

```
function myconf() {
        var cf = $.Deferred();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'feedback/',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'act=cfg',
                success: function(answer) {
                    cf.resolve(answer.configs);
                }
            });
        return cf;
    }
```